# What is the right way to write ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I am solving the pyramid problem, in which an array is reduced to a single element over time by subtracting two consecutive numbers in each iteration.

> **input**: [1, 5, 9, 2, 3, 5, 6]
>
> ***iterations***
>
> [4, 4, -7, 1, 2, 1],
>
> [0, -11, 8, 1, -1],
>
> [-11, 19, -7, -2],
>
> [30, -26, 5],
>
> [-56, 31],
>
> [87]
>
> **output**: 87

What is the best way or ruby way to solve this problem? This can be done by inheriting array and making a new class, but I don't know how. Please help. I write this code to solve it:

```
a = [1,5,9,2,3,5,6]

class Array
  def pyr
    a = self.each_cons(2).to_a.map! { |e| e[1] - e[0] }
    a
  end
end

while a.length > 1
  a = a.pyr
  ans = a[0]
end
p ans
```

Comment: Your current code looks well to me, why use a new class?

Comment: Because I read that it's never a good idea to open a class in ruby. Plus if tomorrow the new requirement comes and then it may create new problems!

Comment: @arpit [You ain't gonna need it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three ways to approach this.

### Reopen the Array class

Sure, if in your particular ruby script/project this is an elementary functionality of an array, reopen the class. But if you are going to re-open a class, at least make sure the name is something meaningful. `pyr`? Why not write a full name, so no conflicts are possible, something like `next_pyramid_iteration` (I have never heard of this pyramid problem, so excuse me if I am way of base here).

### Make a class inherit from Array

```
class Pyramid < Array

  def next_iteration 
    self.each_const(2).map! { |e| e[1] - e[o] }
  end

end
```

and then your calculation would become something like

```
pyramid = Pyramid.new([1,5,9,2,3,5,6])

while pyramid.length > 1
  pyramid.next_iteration
end

pyramid[0]
```

### Make a specific class to do the calculation

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but why not just make a specific class that knows how to calculate pyramids?

```
class PyramidCalculator

  def initialize(arr)
    @pyramid = arr
  end

  def calculate
    while @pyramid.length > 1
      do_next_iteration
    end
    @pyramid.first  
  end 

  def self.calculate(arr)
    PyramidCalculator.new(arr).calculate
  end

  protected

  def do_next_iteration
    @pyramid = @pyramid.each_const(2).map! { |e| e[1] - e[o] }
  end 
end
```

because I added a convenience class-method, you can now calculate a result as follows:

```
PyramidCalculator.calculate([1,5,9,2,3,5,6])
```

My personal preference would be the last option :)

Comment: `self.each_const(2).to_a.map!` can be written as `self.each_const(2).map!`

Comment: Thanks, good tip. I edited my answer. I did not focus on the actual implementation, just how to best organise your ruby code.

Answer (score 3):

I would just do it as a two-liner.

```
a = a.each_cons(2).map{|e1, e2| e2 - e1} while a[1]
a.first # => 87
```

Comment: This is crisp and elegant. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly easy enough to turn this into a simple function without hacking on the Array class:

```
def pyr(ary)
  return ary[0] if ary.length < 2
  pyr(ary.each_cons(2).map { |e| e[1] - e[0] })
end

p pyr [1,5,9,2,3,5,6]    # => 87
```

Use `return ary` if you want the answer as a one-element array rather than a scalar.

If you prefer iteration to recursion or have a very large array:

```
def pyr(ary)
  ary = ary.each_cons(2).map { |e| e[1] - e[0] } while ary.length > 1
  ary
end
```

By encapsulating this as a function rather than doing it inline, you get the ability to do the operation on any number of arrays plus it's non-destructive on the original input array.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to compute the end value by successive computation of differences, which requires `(n*(n-1)/2` subtractions and the same number of additions, where `n` is the size of the array `a`. Instead, we can compute that value by summing `n` terms of the form:

(-1)<sup>K+i</sup>bin_coeff(n-1,i)*a[i]

for `i = 0..(n-1)`, where:

- `K` equals `0` if the array has an even number of elements, else `K` equals `1`; and
- `bin_coeff(n,i)` is the binomial coefficient for choosing "`n` items `i` at a time" (`n!/i!*(n-i)!`).

I know what you're thinking: the calculation of each binomial coefficient will take some work. True, but that can be done in an efficient way (which I've not done below), by computing `bin_coeff(n-1,i+1)` from `bin_coeff(n-1,i)`, etc. Of course, that's academic, as no one is likely to actually use the method I'm suggesting.

(I'm hoping nobody will demand a proof, but I'll try to oblige if a request is made.)

**Code**

```
class Fixnum
  def factorial
    (1..self).reduce(1) { |t,i| t*i }
  end

  def bin_coeff m
    self.factorial/(m.factorial*(self-m).factorial)
  end
end

def pyramid_sum(a)
  n = a.size-1
  sign = n.even? ? -1 : 1
  (0..n).reduce(0) do |t,i|
    sign = -sign
    t + sign * n.bin_coeff(i) * a[i]
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
pyramid_sum [1, 5]                #=> 4 
pyramid_sum [1, 5, 9] #           #=> 0 
pyramid_sum [1, 5, 9, 2]          #=> -11 
pyramid_sum [1, 5, 9, 2, 3]       #=> 30 
pyramid_sum [1, 5, 9, 2, 3, 5]    #=> -56 
pyramid_sum [1, 5, 9, 2, 3, 5, 6] #=> 87
```